# How to get a folder's open icon with SHGetFileInfo() method?

Tags: c++, winapi, shell-icons

This is what I did:

```
LPMALLOC malloc;
LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
SHFILEINFO FileInfo;
SFGAOF sfGao;

if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&malloc))
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHParseDisplayName(strDirPath, NULL, &pidl, SFGAO_FOLDER, &sfGao)))
    {
        SHGetFileInfo((LPCWSTR)(PCHAR(pidl)), 0, &FileInfo, sizeof(FileInfo), SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_ICON);
        CDC* pDC = GetWindowDC();
        pDC->DrawIcon(10, 10, FileInfo.hIcon);
        ReleaseDC(pDC);
    }
    malloc->Free(pidl);
}
malloc->Release();
```

Here's the problem: I found that I can get the icon of a folder easily with this approach. But I could not get its open icon, when I set the fourth parameter of `SHGetFileInfo` method to be `SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_OPENICON`. The `hIcon` of `FileInfo` is always `NULL`, and I don't know why.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Comment: I have resolved the problem. Modify the fourth parameter from SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_OPENICON to SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_OPENICON, then I was able to retrieve the open icon of the specified folder.

Comment: Maybe you should add this as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

I have resolved the problem. Modify the fourth parameter from `SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_OPENICON` to `SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_OPENICON`, then I was able to retrieve the open icon of the specified folder.